# Enterprise Library calling oracle stored procedure with ExecuteSprocAccessor error

Tags: oracle, linq, mapping, enterprise-library

I am doing an MVC Application. I am using Oracle Database with Enterprise Library connection.

The problem I have is to retrieve data when using `ExecuteSprocAccessor`...

When I use `Linq` to bind the data returned it works fine. But when I `ExecuteSprocAccessor` got an error.....`The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure`

```html
Database db = readConfig.ReadWebConfig();
                string SP_NAME = "PKG_AR_PRESUPUESTOS_HS.GET_CAMPANAS";
                
                using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(SP_NAME))
                {

                    dbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_COD_PAIS", DbType.Int32, 32);
                    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_COD_COMPANIA", DbType.Int32, 36);
                    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_COD_MEDIO", DbType.Int32, 4);
                    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_COD_CLIENTE", DbType.Int32, 285);
                    OracleParameter oraPara1 = new OracleParameter("CURSORSALIDA", OracleType.Cursor);
                    oraPara1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(oraPara1);
                    
                      List<Campana> result2 = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand).Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList().ConvertAll(dr => new Campana
                    {
                        COD_CAMPANA = Convert.ToInt32(dr["COD_CAMPANA"].ToString()),
                        COD_COMPANIA = Convert.ToInt32(dr["COD_COMPANIA"].ToString()),
                        COD_PRODUCTO = Convert.ToInt32(dr["COD_PRODUCTO"].ToString()),
                        DES_CAMPANA = dr["DES_CAMPANA"].ToString()
                    });
```

This work fine...

But when I use

```html
Database db = readConfig.ReadWebConfig();
                string SP_NAME = "PKG_AR_PRESUPUESTOS_HS.GET_CAMPANAS";
                
                using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(SP_NAME))
                {

                    dbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_COD_PAIS", DbType.Int32, 32);
                    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_COD_COMPANIA", DbType.Int32, 36);
                    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_COD_MEDIO", DbType.Int32, 4);
                    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_COD_CLIENTE", DbType.Int32, 285);
                    OracleParameter oraPara1 = new OracleParameter("CURSORSALIDA", OracleType.Cursor);
                    oraPara1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(oraPara1);
                    
 List<Campana> result = db.ExecuteSprocAccessor<Campana>(SP_NAME,  dbCommand.Parameters).ToList<Campana>();
```

got an error...`The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure`

Even if i use `Mapping`

```html
                    IRowMapper<Campana> resmapper = MapBuilder<Campana>.MapAllProperties()
                                                  .Map(x => x.COD_CAMPANA).ToColumn("COD_CAMPANA")
                                                  .Map(x => x.COD_COMPANIA).ToColumn("COD_COMPANIA")
                                                  .Map(x => x.DES_CAMPANA).ToColumn("DES_CAMPANA")
                                                  .Map(x => x.COD_PRODUCTO).ToColumn("COD_PRODUCTO")
                                                  .Build();
                    DataTable dt = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand).Tables[0];
                    
   List<Campana> result = db.ExecuteSprocAccessor<Campana>(SP_NAME, resmapper, dbCommand.Parameters).ToList<Campana>();
```

I got the same error...

What is wrong with `ExecuteSprocAccessor`?

Any way, my Campana class look like this.

```html
  public class Campana
    {
        public Int32  COD_COMPANIA { get; set; }
        public Int32 COD_CAMPANA { get; set; }
        public string DES_CAMPANA { get; set; }
        public Int32 COD_PRODUCTO { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should post the code of the stored procedure as well

Answer (score 0):

I solved it passing an object[] instead por cmd.Parameters

```html
object[] param = ParametertoObj(dbCommand);
List<Campana> result = db.ExecuteSprocAccessor<Campana>(SP_NAME, resmapper, param).ToList<Campana>();
```

and my class where I create an array

```html
 public object[] ParametertoObj(DbCommand cmd)
            {
                object[] obj = new object[cmd.Parameters.Count];
                int i = 0;
                foreach (DbParameter item in cmd.Parameters)
                {
                    obj[i] = item.Value;
                    i++;
                }
                return obj;
            }
```